# No session found for current thread, Spring 3.1 & Hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to use delegated Hibernate transactions using Spring in a demo standalone application, using a ***DAO layer*** and a ***Service layer***.

I've properly set configuration, and i've unit-tested that **usage of *@Transactional* annotation on DAO methods is working fine, but when i move this annotation to a *service layer* i get an:**

```java
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

I provide the most relevant parts of my code, hoping you can throw me a hint to understand what's going on here.

## applicationContext.xml

```xml
<beans ...>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.genericdao" />           

    <!-- delegat transactions -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- sessionFactory config -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>        
        <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
            <list>  
                 <value>classpath:com/genericdao/hbm</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect</prop>
                <!--prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop--><!-- i tried commenting this line -->                
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>                    
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop><!-- i know this is provided by default -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        ... i provide here configuration
    </bean>                  
</beans>
```

## Dao layer

***getSession()*** just performs **sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();**
and *sessionFactory* is autowired in *GenericDaoHibernateImpl*

```
@Repository("userLoginDao")
public class UserLoginDaoImpl extends GenericDaoHibernateImpl<UserLogin, Integer> implements UserLoginDao{            

    @Override
    //@Transactional(readOnly=true) // This works when i unit-test!! But I don't want to use @Transactional here!!
    public List<UserLogin> findAll() {        
        boolean active = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(); // always true if i use @Transactional

        Query query = getSession().createQuery("from UserLogin");

        return (List<UserLogin>) query.list();
    }                  
}
```

## Service Layer

```java
@Service("pruebaService")
public class PruebaServiceImpl implements PruebaService{

    private static final ApplicationContext ctx;

    static{
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    }   

    /**********************************************************
     * HERE i want to use @Transactional, but it doesn't work because
     * i get the org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
     * when i test invocation of this method...
     * NOTE: I want to state, that if i uncomment the Dao @Transactional line
     * then this works!!, but as i mentioned before i really don't want to have transactions on DAO methods, just Service Methods!!
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true) 
    public List<UserLogin> obtenerTodasLasCuentas() {
        UserLoginDao bean = (UserLoginDao) ctx.getBean("userLoginDao");
        List<UserLogin> result = bean.findAll();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I really did a serch on this topic but i couldn't find a proper input... hope you can help with this... thanks.

## update:

Here's the testing relevant code i'm using

## testing code

```
@Test
public void selectTest(){
    pruebaService = (PruebaService) ctx.getBean("pruebaService");            
    Assert.assertNotNull(pruebaService); // This assert is good, so i know service is properly injected            
    List<UserLogin> result = pruebaService.obtenerTodasLasCuentas();            
    Assert.assertNotNull(result); // This line is never reached because of the exception i mentioned!!
}
```

Comment: What package is the Service class in?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is probably on the right track.  If Spring is not constructing your `PruebaServiceImpl` class then it won't see the `@Transactional` annotation and can't create the necessary aspect.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis @Pace Service is on `com.genericdao.service` so actually it is created, and it sees `@Transactional` because when i test `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` (DAO findAll method) it always evaluate to true

Comment: Please also show us where you are injecting or using the Service class.

Comment: I think it is happening because of base-package="com.genericdao" .

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i updated the question to show the testing relevant code... thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made this work, I just modified service to this:

```
@Service("pruebaService")
public class PruebaServiceImpl implements PruebaService{

    private @Autowired UserLoginDao userLoginDao; // injected by Spring when I create the ApplicationContext in my unit-testing class


    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=true) 
    public List<UserLogin> obtenerTodasLasCuentas() {        
        List<UserLogin> result = userLoginDao.findAll();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And it was because of misleading the two times created (one in my service and one on my unit-testing classes):

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

If there's something else you want to point... i'd really appreciate your comments... thank you so much for your help guys